# Which is best method to use tab in asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, tabs, webgrid

i must use tab in my view, to manage different type of information.
Now i'm using a webgrid, but i've a problem about a calling method.
I must to view different data from a tab to another tab. I do it using a method which has an id as parameter.

how can i do it?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check Jquery UI tabs ,Its simple. Check below link

[Jquery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)

Comment: thanks dude. but with webgrid i resolved my problems. The main problem is to pass a parameter from view to controller when i switch tab.
How can i resolve this?
have you got an example to show me something.
thanks